# Записать данные из json с использованием метода `cloneNode` и реализовать это по модулю без jQuery

Tags: javascript

Необходимо записать данные из json в `p` по каждому атрибуту (имя, почта, аватарка и тд.) в создаваемый динамически `div` с использованием метода `cloneNode` и реализовать это по модулю.

Вот примерный код:

```
var module_contacts_list = (function () {
    function ajax(url, callback) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', url);
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            //if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200)
            if (this.readyState == 4) {
                if (this.status == 200)
                    callback(JSON.parse(this.responseText));
            }
        };
        xhr.send(null);
    }
    ajax('http://demo.sibers.com/users', function (data) {
        var contact_list = document.getElementById('contacts_list');
        getContacts: function(){
        data.forEach(function (el) {
            var div_contact = document.createElement('div');
                div_contact.className = 'contact';
            var about_contact = document.createElement('p');
            var next_about_contact = about_contact.cloneNode(true);
            about_contact.parentNode.insertBefore(next_about_contact, about_contact.nextSibling);
            var contact_info = document.createTextNode('');
            var contact_name = document.createTextNode(el.name);
            var contact_email = document.createTextNode(el.email);
            div_contact.appendChild(contact_info);
            var img = document.createElement("img");
            img.src = el.avatar;
            div_contact.appendChild(img);
            div_contact.appendChild(about_contact);
            div_contact.appendChild(contact_name);
            div_contact.appendChild(contact_email);
            contact_list.appendChild(div_contact);
        });
    },
    });
})();
```

Полный код тут [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lilubanana/cpu2fahL/6/)

Динамически создаваемая разметка должна быть такая:

```
<div id="contacts_list">
  <div class="contact">
    <img />
    <p>
      name
    </p>
    <p>
      email
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: у вас ошибка в `getContacts: function(){` вы функцию объявляете как метод объекта, а самого объекта нет. так что код даже не запускается, возможно тут нужно было `=`

Comment: если я заменю на `=` это уже будет по модулю?

Comment: нет, но это хотя бы начнет работать :-) сейчас он выдает ошибку: _Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (_

Comment: у меня ошибка возникает `getContacts is not defined`. не знаю что с этим делать

Comment: я не вижу в коде ни одного вызова `getContacts`

Comment: а где его вызывать?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34908/discussion-between-grundy-and-marina-voronova).

Comment: А в чем вопрос-то? Что конкретно не работает?

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, сейчас не в те элементы выводится и не в том формате

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так как есть конкретный шаблон в который надо выводить, то его можно собрать один раз и потом просто клонировать и заполнять данными. Создать можно например в функции

```
function createTemplate() {
    var template = document.createElement('div');
    template.className = "contact";
    template.appendChild(document.createElement('img'));
    return template;
}
```

После этого можно либо каждый раз вызывать эту функцию, либо вызвать один раз и затем просто клонировать готовый элемент.

Для дальнейшей обработки объекта можно использовать цикл `for..in`
В следующем примере если проверяемое свойство строка - то создается абзац, в него добавляется текст, и затем все заносится в созданный ранее шаблон

```
for (var contactProp in contact) {
    if (typeof contact[contactProp] === 'string') {
        var p = document.createElement('p');
        p.innerHTML = contactProp + ": " + contact[contactProp];
        contactElement.appendChild(p);
    }
}
```

Если вы все-таки хотите загружать что-то несколько раз, то данный код можно обернуть в функцию и вернуть из `IIFE`

```
var module_contacts_list = (function() {
   ...
   return {
       loadContacts: function(){ ... }
   }
})();
```

В так случае когда потребуется загрузить контакты, можно просто вызвать метод `loadContacts` у объекта `module_contacts_list`

```
module_contacts_list.loadContacts();
```

Пример:

```js
var module_contacts_list = (function() {
  function ajax(url, callback) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', url);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
      //if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200)
      if (this.readyState == 4) {
        if (this.status == 200)
          callback(JSON.parse(this.responseText));
      }
    };
    xhr.send(null);
  }

  function createTemplate() {
    var template = document.createElement('div');
    template.className = "contact";
    template.appendChild(document.createElement('img'));
    return template;
  }
  return {
    loadContacts: function() {
      ajax('http://demo.sibers.com/users', function(data) {
        var contact_list = document.getElementById('contacts_list');
        var template = createTemplate();

        var res = data.reduce(function(acc, contact) {
          var contactElement = template.cloneNode(true);
          contactElement.querySelector('img').src = contact.avatar;
          delete contact.avatar;
          for (var contactProp in contact) {
            if (typeof contact[contactProp] === 'string') {
              var p = document.createElement('p');
              p.innerHTML = contactProp + ": " + contact[contactProp];
              contactElement.appendChild(p);
            }
          }
          acc.appendChild(contactElement);
          return acc;
        }, document.createDocumentFragment());
        contact_list.appendChild(res);
      });
    }
  }
})();

module_contacts_list.loadContacts();
```

```css
.contact {
  clear: both;
  border: 1px solid #F62459;
  margin: 5px 0;
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
.contact img {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 15px;
  max-height: 100px;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="contacts_list"></div>
```

Comment: спасибо большое! буду разбираться

Comment: эту строку не могу понять `contactElement.querySelector('img').src = contact.avatar; delete contact.avatar;`

Comment: т.е. зачем удаляем? `contact.avatar;`

Comment: и еще вопрос ,почему именно метод `reduce()` ?

Comment: `ontactElement.querySelector('img').src = contact.avatar; delete contact.avatar;` - устанавливаем src для img - чтобы картинка показывалась, и удаляем это свойство, чтобы потом в цикле оно не мешалось

Comment: `reduce` - потому что в нем в один большой кусок собираются все элементы с классом contact, и потом сразу все вставляются в контейнер

Comment: а как задать класс какому-нибудь одному `p` в диве?

Comment: @MarinaVoronova, например так же как в функции темлейта я задаю: ` template.className = "contact";` только вместо `template` используйте нужный `p` элемент.

Comment: а как задать нужный `p` элемент? там их несколько? через массив ? т.е. если я хочу обратиться к первому элементу ,то как-то так `[0]` ?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35008/discussion-between-grundy-and-marina-voronova).